# How can I search for all files that have their archive bit set in Windows 7?

Tags: windows, search

Due to a failed TFS server I've lost my workspace and have to redownload all the source again to resync my local files with the server files. Unfortunately I have a bunch of files checked out for edit and I know from past experience that TFS doesn't cope with this situation and the only resolution option for files that are writeable is to overwrite them with the server version thus losing all my edits*

So prior to doing the "Get Latest" and overwriting all the files I need to copy out all the files that have been modified. The simplest way to do this is to check for those files that have their archive bit set.

How do I do this from the Windows Explorer search bar so I can then just do a <kbd>Cntl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> followed by a <kbd>Cntl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to get all the files and then back them up somewhere outside the source tree?

* *Yes I know I should check stuff in more frequently than I do*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It turns out that there is a "hidden" advanced search option:

> attributes:

which will search for files with various attribute bits set:

> attributes:16 is D
>   attributes:32 is A
>   attributes:33 is RA
>   attributes:34 is HA

As the [source](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/w7itproui/thread/fede1d8e-130c-4e69-9b2b-48cf3f904c43) states there will be other options that allow you to find other combinations, but what worked for me was to enter:

> attributes:32 *.cs

which found all the source files I'd modified.

Comment: Wow, you just gotta love how “user-friendly” the new (at that time) Windows Explorer search function is. Learning about bit-fields and doing bitwise math is *so* much easier for novice users than simply checking check-boxes or using text strings. ◔_◔      (Also, this makes it very difficult to search for a single attribute regardless of others. For example, to search for hidden objects, you have to search for `H`, `H+A`, `H+R`, `H+S`, `H+R+A`, `H+R+S`, `H+R+A+S`, let alone `…+I…`, `…+E…`, etc. *So many* permutations.)